# How to open an Excel on a particular cell using a URL

Tags: excel, url, format

I'd like to have an HTML file with a URL that points to particular cell in local Excel file.
For example using file://temp/Workbook.xlsx#Sheet1!$A$5 opens the Workbook.xlsx spreadsheet with the cursor already at A5 on sheet Sheet1.
Couldn't find a URL format for that.
Is that possible?

Comment: interesting request. how about having a garden-variety link to an Excel file, and in that file using VBA -- in the Workbook_Open event -- to go to sheet1, cell A5?

Comment: But I need to receive sheet and cell as parameters from the link

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem ? I've the same requirements